# Allocate memory in child and share with parent

Tags: c, memory-management, shared-memory

Is it possible to share memory that was allocated in a child process created with `fork()` with the parent process using `C`? If yes, can you provide a minimal example? I cannot find any good examples even after a lot of searching. I have only shared memory from parent to child using `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED`.

Comment: Maybe by using *shared memory*. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of parent/child, but of before/after the `fork()`. If you want to setup a shared memory space *after* the fork, you can use `shmget()`/`shmat()` in parent and child.

This for example had to be called in both processes:

```
int shmid = shmget(0x31337, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)
char *shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)
```

It is not possible to do some call in the child, which makes the shared memory "magically" appear in the parent (or the other way round).